# Why doesn't a shorter shutter time cause less capture time/ readout time?

Tags: technique, shutter-speed, physics, theory

If I make a video @ 120 FPS and a shutter speed of 1/12000 from my pwm controlled lamp, which flickers at around 1300 Hz, I get those 11 rolling shutter bars: [image]

(11 Cycles in 1/120s equals around 1300Hz)

Now, if I vary the shutter speed I still get 11 bars, they just look a little brighter with a slower one:
[image]

I don't understand why? I mean let's take the first example with 1/12000 shutter speed:

The sensor is just 1/12000s exposed to the flickering lamp, stops exposure and then reads out with a speed of 1/120s. How can there still be 11 bars? One cycle needs 1/1300s, so in 1/12000s exposure time, there can only be 0,1083 cycle(s) (so only around 10% of one full cycle).

I would have thought, that a faster shutter speed would result in less bars (maybe we open the shutter in the "on" cycle and close it right before the "off" beginns) and a slower one in more but that's not the case... It stays the same but why?

Comment: What camera are you using? And I count 16 bars in the 2nd picture?

Comment: @user24582 the camera of my galaxy s23, yes you're right the 2nd photo was wrong (other frame rate), corrected it :)

Comment: Is the PWM lamp the only light source in both examples?

Comment: @EuriPinhollow yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sensor lines can be left in integration mode (turned on) for as long as necessary to make an exposure brighter or darker.

But a sensor line cannot be read out and reset until the previous sensor line has completed readout/reset. The readout/reset time is the fastest it can switch between lines and that dictates the minimum number of bands you can record.

No matter how short the exposure time, it requires no less than 1/120 for your phone's camera. What happens at higher SS's, where exposure time is less than readout/reset, is that the sensor lines' exposures loose temporal alignment with real time. And that's why you are still recording the same 11 bars... portions of the 1/120 required time are not being recorded in order to achieve the reduced exposure.

[image]

Comment: Is the shutter speed literally a pulse width of sensitivity?  Are rolling shutter bars directly proportional in length to shutter time?

Comment: @davolfman, yes electronic shutter speed is a pulse width ("ON" time) of sensitivity. Not sure what you mean by "shutter bars."

Answer (score 0):

Shutter readout time is in no way obliged to change depending on the exposure time. Exposure has no effect on readout. It's the other way around: exposure cannot be shorter than 2x shutter readout time (readout begins immediately after exposure start).

Instead what a reading circuit can do is to skip some pixel lines, that would indeed help. Up to some moment all of high resolution photo cameras were skipping lines to record video since the readout was very slow.

Also, I have no idea how S23's sensor specifics but you've clearly demonstrated that it has a rolling shutter and it's probably shutting whole frame in 1/24000 s (if 1/12000 is the hard minimum then it's probably why). If it's skipping the pixel lines (it probably does it in 120 FPS mode independent of requested exposure time) it very well might work that quickly.

I did not try to verify your data but you pointed out that 1/12000s is much faster than 1/(1kHz) so a smartphone is expected to only output images without narrow stripes if it takes whole frames. Therefore, my best guess is that smartphone is not exposing full sensor at any time and is exposing and reading pixel lines as it scans the frame. Then it won't be required to read out the sensor in 1/24000s. It's slightly similar to how mechanical shutter can get exposure times much faster than the shutter roll time - the image is produced by a sliding slit.

Comment: But if doesn't shut a frame in 1/120s but, like you assume, very very faster, my pwm lamp (Philips Hue White & Color Ambiance E27 LED) would have a much higher frequency than around 1kHz. (And it's verified that it must be somewhere around 1kHz in the community)

Comment: (1/12000s shutter speed is the fastest one)

Comment: I mean 11/(1/120s) = 1320 Hz. Whereby 11/(1/12000s) would be 132000 Hz (which the hue lamp for sure doesn't have)

Comment: And wouldn't the quality go down if it skips rows to achieve 1/12000s? I still get photos in full 50M quality

Comment: Or does faster shutter speed mean: Exposing each row shorter BUT moving on to the next row is the same speed as before (and adding together all exposure durations at the last row equals the set shutter speed)? That would explain, why the rolling shutter effect gets more obvious with faster shutter time and why I still get 11 bars no matter what shutter speed I set.

Comment: @iwab I updated the answer.